# Need matching class for LoggersMvcEndpoint. in spring-boot 2.1.9 release

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am upgrading my project from spring-boot 1.5.12.release to 2.1.9.release. I am unable to find LoggersMvcEndpoint (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.12.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/LoggersMvcEndpoint.html) in latest version. 
In one of my controller I had this. Can some one help me to fix this.

```
 public class LoggerController extends CloudRestTemplate {
@Autowired
LoggersMvcEndpoint loggerAPI;

 @Override
public Object getFromInternalApi(final String param) {
    return StringUtils.isEmpty(param) ? loggerAPI.invoke() : loggerAPI.get(param);
}

@Override
public Object postToInternalApi(final String param, final Object request) {
    return loggerAPI.set(param, (Map<String, String>) request);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As per Spring docs [here](https://spring.io/blog/2017/08/22/introducing-actuator-endpoints-in-spring-boot-2-0)

> **Endpoint infrastructure**
>
> Spring Boot 2 brings a brand new endpoint
>   infrastructure that allows you to define one or several operations in
>   a technology independent fashion with support for Spring MVC, Spring
>   WebFlux and Jersey! Spring Boot 2 will have native support for Jersey
>   and writing an adapter for another JAX-RS implementation should be
>   easy as long as there is a way to programmatically register resources.
>
> The new @Endpoint annotation declares this type to be an endpoint with
>   a mandatory, unique id. As we will see later, a bunch of properties
>   will be automatically inferred from that. No additional code is
>   required to expose this endpoint at /applications/loggers or as a
>   org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=Loggers JMX MBean.

Refer to documentation, it will help you further

and for your info **LoggersMvcEndpoint** was there until **2.0.0.M3** https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/LoggersMvcEndpoint.html however there is no reference of deprecation in subsequent version's release notes of **2.0.0.M4**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M4/api/deprecated-list.html#class

Comment: Okay. But we don't have invoke and get methods in the LoggersEndpoint class.

Comment: For that exploring  Actuator Endpoints in Spring Boot 2.0 would help

Comment: Thank you. Can you please look into it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305840/looing-for-matched-cachepublicmetrics-in-spring-boot-2-1-9-release and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303679/looking-for-matched-passwordencoder-in-spring-boot-2-1-9-release