# Looking for matched password encoder in Spring Boot 2.1.9 release

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am upgrading my project from spring-boot 1.5.12.release to 2.1.9.release. I am unable to find matching encoder for `org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder` in latest version. The following is the code snippet I had it in my code.

```java
@Autowired
private ShaPasswordEncoder encoder;

[...]

    String passwordHash = encoder.encode((String)auth.getCredentials());

    if (cachedAuth!=null && encoder.isPasswordValid((String) cachedAuth.getCredentials(), password, salt)){ 
        return cachedAuth;
    }
```

I found this class `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder` in Spring Boot 2.1.9 release but I don't have this method `isPasswordValid()` here. Can you please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The SHA password encoder was already deprecated in Spring Security 4.2.12, see [`ShaPasswordEncoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/ShaPasswordEncoder.html):

> **Deprecated.**
>
> This is deprecated and marked for deletion. Replace with an implementation of `MessageDigestPasswordEncoder` with an algorithm "SHA-$strength" (i.e. "SHA-1" or "SHA-256").

It was removed in Spring Security 5, but you could still use [`MessageDigestPasswordEncoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.html).

Comment: infact MessageDigestPasswordEncoder is also deprecated but not marked for deletion yet

Comment: @Shailesh Yes, you are right. It (deprecated) is documented in the link, which I provided.

Comment: Ok. Then What's the best match to use?

Comment: I added this way. Please validate.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Bean
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public PasswordEncoder delegatingPasswordEncoder() {
    PasswordEncoder defaultEncoder = new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
     encoders.put("SHA-256", new 
  org.springframework.security.crypto.password.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("SHA-256"));
    DelegatingPasswordEncoder passworEncoder = new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(
      "bcrypt", encoders);
    passworEncoder.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(defaultEncoder); 
    return passworEncoder;
}
```