# Looking for Matched CachePublicMetrics in spring-boot 2.1.9.release

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cache

I am using following  classes in one of controllers of (spring-boot.1.5.12 release)

I am unable to find matching classes in spring 2.1.9 release.

The following is the code snippet

```
        import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.CachePublicMetrics;
        import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.Metric;  

        public class CachingController extends CloudRestTemplate {

        @Autowired
        private CachePublicMetrics metrics;

        public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> getData(@Pattern(regexp=Constants.STRING_VALID_PATTERN, message=Constants.STRING_INVALID_MSG) @PathVariable(required = true) final String name) throws Exception {
        boolean success = false;
        Map<String, Object> m = Maps.newHashMap();
        Collection<Metric<?>> resp = new ArrayList<>();
        Collection<Metric<?>> mets = metrics.metrics();

        for (Iterator<Metric<?>> iterator = mets.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Metric<?> met = iterator.next();
        String metName = met.getName();
        logger.debug(metName+":"+met.getValue());

        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(metName)
        && metName.indexOf(name) != -1 ){
        resp.add(met);
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: @Shailesh can you check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a deeper look into Spring boot actuator, once you expose your all endpoints you might find what you are looking for. Spring Boot provides bunch of pre-defined endpoints, below is a list of Spring boot actuator endpoints ([source](https://www.amitph.com/spring-boot-actuator-spring-boot-2/))

> - /auditevents: Exposes audit events information for the current    application.
> - /beans: Returns list of all spring beans in the    application.
> - /caches: Gives information about the available caches.
> - /health: Provides applications health information.
> - /conditions:    Provides list of conditions those were evaluated    during auto configurations.
> - /configprops: Returns list of application level    properties.
> - /info: Provides information about current application.    This info    can be configured in a properties file.
> - /loggers: Displays    logging configurations. Moreover, this endpoint    can be used to modify    the configurations.
> - /headdump: Produces a head dump file and returns    it.
> - /metrics: Returns various metrics about the application. Includes      memory, heap and threads info. However, this endpoint doesn’t return  any metrics. While, it only returns list of available metrics, the
>     metrics names can be used in a separate request to fetch the respective details. For instance, /actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.max like this.
> - /scheduledtasks: Returns a list of Scheduled tasks in the       application.
> - /httptrace: Returns last 100 http interactions in the    form of    request and response. Including, the actuator endpoints.
> - /mappings: List of all Http Request Mappings. Also includes the actuator endpoints.

**Edit:**

As discussed in comments, you need to access */actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.max* , you can invoke same using RestTemplate if you want to access using Java, you need to explore Actuator APIs, I wrote a quick program, you can refer the same

```
@Autowired
private MetricsEndpoint metricsEndpoint;

public MetricResponse printJavaMaxMemMetrics() {

        ListNamesResponse listNames = metricsEndpoint.listNames();

        listNames.getNames().stream().forEach(name -> System.out.println(name));

        MetricResponse metric = metricsEndpoint.metric("jvm.memory.max", new ArrayList<>());
        System.out.println("metric (jvm.memory.max) ->" + metric);

        List<AvailableTag> availableTags = metric.getAvailableTags();

        availableTags.forEach(tag -> System.out.println(tag.getTag() + " : " + tag.getValues()));

        List<Sample> measurements = metric.getMeasurements();
        measurements.forEach(sample -> System.out.println(sample.getStatistic() + " : " + sample.getValue()));

        return metric;

    }
```

Comment: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-actuator/ I have seen this. http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/{MetricName}. How do I call to this end point in my getData() in order to read the metrics of the given name?

Comment: Yes. They are already given. /actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.max  example. this one. Should I call i using rest template in my getData()

Comment: Yes that's one way, edited my answer to put some code

Comment: yes. I did that. but I have not tested. I will let you know once I test it